# My jQuery will not activate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

My jQuery will not activate on click as it should. I am targeting all class a divs
http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/BbSMW/6/     (JSFiddle)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".a").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(default:400);
});
});
```

Comment: That is because your fiddle does not have jQuery in it...

Comment: Your jsfiddle javascript code does not match the code you've posted here? Which one should we be helping with?

Comment: Use the console (F12 on most browsers) and you'll see why! - `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: You are not loading jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle does not have jQuery in it and you forgot quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/KMjG6/